# Find and replace numbers in an R txt file

Tags: r, regex, text-files, gsub, hashtag

I am attempting to find all sentences in a text file in [r](/questions/tagged/r) that have numbers of any format in them and replace it with hashtags around them.

for example take the input below:

```
ex <- c("I have $5.78 in my account","Hello my name is blank","do you want 1,785 puppies?", 
        "I love stack overflow!","My favorite numbers are 3, 14,568, and 78")
```

as the output of the function, I'm looking for:

```
 > "I have #$5.78# in my account" 
 > "do you want #1,785# puppies?"
 > "My favorite numbers are #3#, #14,568#, and #78#"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surrounding numbers is straight-forward, assuming that anything with a number, period, comma, and dollar-sign are all included.

```r
gsub("\\b([-$0-9.,]+)\\b", "#\\1#", ex)
# [1] "I have $#5.78# in my account"                   
# [2] "Hello my name is blank"                         
# [3] "do you want #1,785# puppies?"                   
# [4] "I love stack overflow!"                         
# [5] "My favorite numbers are #3#, #14,568#, and #78#"
```

To filter out just the numbered entries:

```r
grep("\\d", gsub("\\b([-$0-9.,]+)\\b", "#\\1#", ex), value = TRUE)
# [1] "I have $#5.78# in my account"                   
# [2] "do you want #1,785# puppies?"                   
# [3] "My favorite numbers are #3#, #14,568#, and #78#"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("(?<=\\s)(?=[$0-9])|(?<=[0-9])(?=,?[ ]|$)", "#", ex, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "I have #$5.78# in my account"                   "Hello my name is blank"                        
#[3] "do you want #1,785# puppies?"                   "I love stack overflow!"                        
#[5] "My favorite numbers are #3#, #14,568#, and #78#"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another step-by-step approach is to use `grep` to identify the elements of text file containing the pattern `"[0-9]"`, subset text elements with numeric entries using `ex[....]`, and use the pipe operator `%>%` from `library(dplyr)` to pass the subset to `gsub` then use @r2evans' logic to place hashtags around numeric entries as shown below:

```
library(dplyr) 
ex[do.call(grep,list("[0-9]",ex))] %>% gsub("\\b([-$0-9.,]+)\\b", "#\\1#",.)
```

> The `do.call(grep,list("[0-9]",ex))` portion of the code returns the indices for the text elements in ex with numeric entries.
>
> Output

```
library(dplyr) 
ex[do.call(grep,list("[0-9]",ex))] %>% gsub("\\b([-$0-9.,]+)\\b", "#\\1#",.)

[1] "I have $#5.78# in my account"   "do you want #1,785# puppies?"                   
[3] "My favorite numbers are #3#, #14,568#, and #78#"
```